# Ajax call failing, but only on a certain cell carrier

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a website that's running at www.example.com. When the page is loaded a JavaScript file is fetched that makes an Ajax call to xyz.subdomain.example.com.

Everything works on every platform/browser I've tested except for one. Things fail when I run this on my Android cellphone (regardless of browser used, although things work if I enable WiFi). However, things work correctly on my wife's cellphone which connects to a different carrier (yes, we have 2 companies - long story).

When things fail, the status that I receive is 0 with no additional text. My gut feeling is that this could be a CORS problem, but who gets to make the call? I'd assume the browser does, I'd believe the OS, but I can't accept that the carrier is doing this.

Is there another explanation as to what's going on? Any idea how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

I've made a little bit of progress, but haven't solved the problem. Thanks to everyone who helped.

My original explanation is a bit simplified. I'm actually trying to go to random.xyz.subdomain.example.com and then watching what happens at the DNS server (that I control).

Anyway, I decided to install termux and it's great. Here's what I found:

```
dig random.xyz.subdomain.example.com
```

Resolves correctly. FWIW, Google DNS is being used here.

```
curl random.xyz.subdomain.example.com
```

Received Error:   curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host random.xyz.subdomain.example.com

OK, that was unexpected. The domain resolves with dig, but curl has a problem.

At this point I turn WiFi on on the phone

```
curl random.xyz.subdomain.example.com
```

A bunch of data is correctly returned.

This seems a bit weird. I think it means that the carrier is not the problem, the phone is. Or more specifically, the mobile code in the phone because WiFi works beautifully. Is this right? What else should I test?

And if it means anything, the phone is a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime (SM-G530W) running Android 5.1.1

**EDIT 2**

I was troubled by the different behavior between dig and curl and started looking into that. I did see some people reference this issue but not fully solve it. I also noticed that the behavior that I found on my phone could also be duplicated from a stock AWS Linux instance.

I also realized that the process of resolving the name of the nameserver that controlled the zone for random.xyz.subdomain.example.com was very complex. It consisted of following a few CNAMEs through resources controlled by 3 different companies. This whole process works, but apparently doesn't for certain instances.

Anyway, I made the resolution of the name of this nameserver much simpler and now things work everywhere. I think that the ultimate problem was some older and buggy library deep in Linux networking that wasn't properly parsing or dealing with some condition that rarely happens.

Comment: Might be a DNS problem of the carrier. You can try to debug using chrome and see the request your android is doing and what you get in return from the server.

Comment: If you're using an Android phone, you can connect it to Chrome on your PC and debug the page, including network traffic, etc. That might at least provide some clues about what the request and response looks like

Answer (score 4):

On android there's many ways to debug this, probably the easiest is to connect your chrome's remote debugger to the problematic phone, and check the console and the network tab for further explanations.

If it doesn't help, google your isp/cell provider, the phone model, just in case it's a known "feature".

You can check your remote ip from the server's aspect of view, or just ask google "what is my ip", "what is my user agent". It might happen that security /privacy / other good or bad willing (sometimes system) apps are hijacking http traffic.

In case it turns out to be a network problem, and you're familiar with consoles, getting an app like termux might help a lot. Standard tools like curl, ping, traceroute etc. might help identify the root cause.

Comment: termux was a good idea. I tried it out and some weirdness happened that is documented as an edit on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Place a "test" page on `xyz.subdomain.example.com` and directly access it on the phone with the issue using the same browser.

If you can not get to the test page, contact the provider (and you have a test page to show them).

If you can access the test page in the browser but not with an ajax call, something very strange is going on.

The only other thing I can think of is the phone itself has some crap code that is overriding the request because of the `path` in the ajax request URL. I have seen this before and it was tricky to debug. To test this wacky idea, try renaming the ajax requested file.

**Edit**: As Phil said below. It might be a good idea to swap SIM with your wife to cross check if it is carrier or phone issue.

Comment: OP says it works on WiFi so I don't think your last paragraph applies

Comment: @Phil You can't trust mobile phone coders. It is possible the "crap code" only kicks in under a non-wifi network connection.

Comment: Good point. OP could do some isolation tests by swapping SIMs with his wife. Would narrow down the problem to either the phone or the carrier.